# How do I get the execution time of a Perl program?

Tags: perl

How can I get execution time if I stop it? Example I run my perl script and I press terminal shortcut CTRL+C or CTRL+Z to stop it, then post the execution time. This is posible or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux, you can use the [program `time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) to get the execution time. Just prepend it to your Perl script like this.

```
$ cat foo.pl
1 while 1;
$ time perl foo.pl
^C
real    0m1.006s
user    0m0.756s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Of course this is not limited to Perl programs. It works for any program.

Answer (score 3):

Perl has a built in variable called: `$^T` which is start time of the program.

Note - on Unix `CTRL-Z` *stops* a process (SIGSTP) (which can be continued) where `CTRL-C` causes it to exit. (SIGINT)

Adding a handler for `SIGINT` would be something like this.

```
$SIG{'INT'} = sub { warn "Start time: $^T\n, Run time:".( time() - $^T)."\n" };
```

Note - this won't actually bomb out your program any more - if you're doing this, you should probably `die` as well, otherwise the program will do something unexpected (e.g. not exit on a `Ctrl-C` - but that's ok, if it's aborting a 'current operation')

So normally you'd hook one of the *other* signals, like `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` which are explicitly for user-defined functionality. (You can then `kill -USR1 <pid>`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{'INT'} = sub { warn "Started at $^T, runtime ".(time() - $^T)."\n"; die };
$SIG{'USR1'} = sub { warn "Started at $^T, runtime ".(time() - $^T)."\n"; 
                     warn "Program continuing\n"; };

while ( 1 ) {
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Nit: Ctrl-Z (on unix) sends `SIGTSTP`, so you could trap it if you wanted to. Not very useful here, though. I'm thinking he might be on Windows, where Ctrl-Z results in EOF (similar to Ctrl-D in unix).

Comment: By 'not working' what's the error you get? (note, tweaked it a bit... )

Comment: `ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ perl test.pl
^CStarted at 1446736069, runtime 1
Died at test.pl line 5.`

Comment: Yes. You pressed ctrl-c  - it reported a 1s runtime. then exited.